# Sorting five lists in python according to one list

Tags: python, sorting, csv

So, I have five lists.

```
placeName
placeType
population
latitude
longitude
```

Now, I want to sort according to population. The lists all come with title headers (it's imported from a .csv file) so I strip those using

```
del list[0]
```

Here's my problem. If I run this sort:

```
sortedPop = sorted(population, key=float, reverse=True);
```

I get a correctly sorted population list:

```
['8173941', '1085810', '589900', '552267', '535907', '518090', '510746', '474632', '468720', '443760', '349561', '335145', '325949', '289301', '284321', '270726', '268064', '265178', '255394', '253651', '238137', '234982', '229700', '218791', '218705', '215173', '211228', '194189', '189120', '187503', '186682', '182441', '179485', '175547', '174700', '174286', '171750', '165456', '162949', '161707', '159994', '155298', '154718', '152841', '147663', '145818', '144957', '144170', '142968', '142723', '136362', '134022', '131982', '128060', '123187', '120256', '120046', '119441', '117963', '116447', '113507', '110507', '109805', '109691', '109185', '109120', '109015', '107926', '107627', '107355', '107123', '106943', '105878', '105367', '104157', '103886', '103608', '102885', '100160', '100153', '99251', '97886', '96555', '95580', '94932', '94782', '92363', '91930', '91703', '91297', '91053', '89663', '88855', '88483', '88243', '88134', '87590', '86552', '86011', '83641']
```

If I run this:

```
popPlace = zip(population, placeName);
popPlace.sort(reverse=True);
```

I don't:

```
[('99251', 'Wakefield'), ('97886', 'Preston'), ('96555', 'Oldham'), ('95580', 'Rayleigh'), ('94932', 'Hemel Hempstead'), ('94782', 'Bath'), ('92363', 'Darlington'), ('91930', 'West Bromwich'), ('91703', 'Southport'), ('91297', 'Barnsley'), ('91053', 'Hastings'), ('89663', 'Stevenage'), ('88855', 'Hartlepool'), ('88483', 'Chesterfield'), ('88243', 'Grimsby'), ('88134', 'Halifax'), ('87590', 'Bedford'), ('86552', 'Nuneaton'), ('86011', 'Chester'), ('83641', 'Weston-Super-Mare'), ('8173941', 'London'), ('589900', 'Glasgow'),
```

etc.

Basically, it can't sort numbers with different orders of magnitude, unless given the key=float. However, I can't use key=float on the zip, since it gives me an error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number.

So, how do I get this thing to sort correctly?

Also, can all five lists be bundled into a single zip and sorted correctly? I assume it's just `zip(placeName,placeType,population,latitude,longitude)` etc.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a list of dictionaries .

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should be using pandas for all of this since it will provide you with a nice table structure for your data rather than having to keep track of separate lists (see http://pandas.pydata.org/).

For this particular case, using `key=float` fails in the second example because instead of just iterating over strings that can be directly converted to numbers, you're iterating over (population, name) tuples. You can use something like `key=lambda x: int(x[0])` in the sort, but you're going to be better off converting the populations to integers by adding a line `population = map(int, population)` before doing any of these operations.

Comment: This worked using `key=lambda x: int(x[0])`. There's some good examples [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)

Comment: Yeah, the underlying issue is that when you sort numbers stored as strings, it tries to do an alphabetic-style sort rather than a numeric one, so just as "art" comes before "bee", "809" comes before "90" since 8 < 9. By adding the `int` conversion in the key, `sorted` then does a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need a sorted tuple instead:

```
list_tuples =[('99251', 'Wakefield'), ('97886', 'Preston')]
print sorted(list_tuples, key=lambda popu: int(popu[0]))
>>> [('97886', 'Preston'), ('99251', 'Wakefield')]
```

Comment: This actually still doesn't work if you pick different values. Try list_tuples=[('83641', 'Weston-Super-Mare'), ('8173941', 'London'), ('589900', 'Glasgow')], as these demonstrate how it doesn't seem to be able to tell a 7 digit number from a 5 digit one.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the population list to integers with:

```
population = [int(x) for x in population]
```

and then the sorting will work

Comment: I get this one now: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'. Seems it's a tuple, not a list.

Comment: you should do it before 'zip' when population still contains strings